# Path match but (vue) router-view display wrong component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

As the title, I have this strange bug.

[image]

My router "index.js"

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      breadcrumb: "Home",
    },
    children: [      
      {
        path: "login",
        name: "login",
        component: Login,
        meta: {
          breadcrumb: "login",
        },
      },
      {
        path: "forgot-password",
        name: "forgot-password",
        component: ForgotPassword,
        meta: {
          breadcrumb: "forgot-password",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I don't know what information needed to provide more so tell me.

Comment: Show **Home** lines where you use **router-link**

Comment: Better will be demonstration in **codesandbox**